# How to create Mega zoom camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I am working on android app where i want to increase the Zoom level of camera. Actually  i want to make the camera zoom like the Google Play Store app mention in the link.
[Mega zoom camera android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usefullapps.megazoomcamera)

I can use the Mobile phone zoom feature but it is very low if i compare it with the zoom function provided in the above given app.
Below is the code where i control zoom with zoom-control button

```
 zoomSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null); 
            zoomSeekBar.setMax(preview.getMaxZoom());
            zoomSeekBar.setProgress(preview.getMaxZoom()-preview.getCameraController().getZoom());
            zoomSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    preview.zoomTo(preview.getMaxZoom() - progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: you can zoom the view itself. But the image quality will decrease correcponding.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Can you please tell me how exactly i can zoom the view. i have posted the code, can you help me regard that. I am getting 30 value with above preview.getMaxZoom() function.